# Property or variable in css file

Tags: css

is there any possibility to use any properties/env-variable in css file.
In my css file I have following part:

```
 background: #F6F6F6 url("http://localhost:3000/images/cropped_logo_baga_black.png") no-repeat center;
```

and now I want to have base url in any external config file to be able to do sth like this

```
 background: #F6F6F6 url("${BASE_URL}/images/cropped_logo_baga_black.png") no-repeat center;
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Not quite yet in pure CSS, [but it's getting there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). For now you can use variables in [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use in css "var" to do that.

```
:root {
   --base-url: http://localhost:3000;
}
.yourclass{
   background: #F6F6F6 url("var(--base-url)/images/cropped_logo_baga_black.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

moz dev: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

can i use: https://caniuse.com/#search=var

Comment: On mozilla.com: "This is an experimental technology", and its not really available right now. Nice future feature though!

Comment: it work perfectly now at all currently common browsers ;) How you see at:
https://caniuse.com/#search=var

Comment: True, but please also take into account the "usage relative" tab. There you can see that none of the currently used IE (duh), Edge, Android, etc. browsers actually support it. So, when using this for example for a website viewed on Android, it might not render as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no real way of having variables in CSS.

You might be able to (mis)use the attr() function though.

```
a:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_attr.asp

Otherwise, you might want to take a look at CSS Preprocessors like:
Sass (http://sass-lang.com/) or Less.js (http://lesscss.org/).

More info on various preprocessors here: https://www.sitepoint.com/6-current-options-css-preprocessors/